# Laravel route problem redirects 404 error

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a problem, I made a support system, and when I want to enter the page where I watch the ticket, I will get 404 not found. Basically the route is that of the id in the database.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/viewTickets', 'TicketController@view_MyTickets')->name('viewTickets');

Route::get('/viewTickets/{ticket}', 'TicketController@view_MyTicketUpdate')->name('updateTicket');

Route::post('/viewTickets/{ticket}', 'TicketController@update_MyTicket');
```

Controller:

```
public function view_MyTickets() {
    $tickets = Ticket::latest()->get();
    return view('viewTickets', compact('tickets'));
}

public function view_MyTicketUpdate() {
    $tickets = Ticket::latest()->get();
    return view('updateTicket', compact('tickets'));
}
```

View:

```
<tbody>
             @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$ticket->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$ticket->user_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$ticket->title}}</td>
                    <td>{{$ticket->category}}</td>
                    <td>{{$ticket->status}}</td>
                    <td>
                    <form>
                        <a href="{{ $ticket->id }}" class="view" title="View" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE417;</i></a>
                        <a href="{{ $ticket->id }}"lass="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>

                    </td>
                </form>
                </tr>
             @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

I really don't understand the problem, a way to solve and did not receive error 404? Btw, I read the other topics and I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: To make the question clearer, could you tell us the exact URL you're trying to hit, and the error you're getting?

Comment: Are you trying to hit this URL?
<your domain name>/viewTickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you are setting in the href attribute is only the ticket id, but it should be, for example, "/viewTickets/1"

Try to put this:

```
href="{{route('updateTicket', ['ticket' => $ticket->id])}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route :

```
Route::get('/viewTickets', 'TicketController@view_MyTickets')->name('viewTickets');
Route::get('/viewTickets/{ticket}', 'TicketController@view_MyTicketUpdate')->name('updateTicket');
Route::post('/viewTickets/{ticket}', 'TicketController@update_MyTicket');
```

In your Controller :

```
public function view_MyTickets() {
    $tickets = Ticket::latest()->get();
    return view('viewTickets', compact('tickets'));
}

public function view_MyTicketUpdate(Request $request, $ticket) {
    $tickets = Ticket::find($ticket);
    return view('updateTicket', compact('tickets'));
}
```

In your Blade :

```
<tbody>
 @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$ticket->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$ticket->user_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$ticket->title}}</td>
        <td>{{$ticket->category}}</td>
        <td>{{$ticket->status}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('viewTickets', ['ticket' => $ticket->id])  }}" class="view" title="View" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE417;</i></a>
            <a href="{{ route('updateTicket', ['ticket' => $ticket->id])  }}"lass="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>
```